# Understanding 彼奴め and 〜やがる

Tags: colloquial-language

I'm steadily learning the language, but sometimes I find these little things I can't really grasp. Today doing some reading for fun I found this particular sentence:

> **彼奴め**調子に**のってやがりますから**、我らでこらしめてやりましょう

The part about “彼奴め” and the “のってやがりますから” is the one giving me the most trouble. I can get a basic grasp of what it's trying to convey, but I want to be able to learn how to utilize that construction correctly in the future should I need to.

Could someone please share some insight on it? The context is referring to a group plotting against someone.

Comment: Do you have a more specific question you might be able to ask about it?

Comment: Surelly do. The part about "彼奴め" and the "のってやがりますから” are the ones giving me the most trouble. I can get a basic grasp of what it's trying to convey, but I want to be able to learn how to utilize that construction correctly in the future should I need to.

Answer (score 5):

The structure of the sentence is :

> "Reason (1st half) + Action taken for that reason (2nd half)."

Vocabulary:

> [彼奴]{きゃつ}め : a most disdainful singular third-person pronoun
>
> [調子]{ちょうし}に[乗]{の}る : to press one's luck
>
> やがる : a verb suffix expressing contempt
>
> こらしめる : to teach one a lesson, to punish

My own TL attempt:

> "The bastard is really pressing his luck; Let's give him a lesson!"

Comment: First of all, I really appreciate you taking your time to answer this!

About the question though, are there any grammatical rules attached to the usage of やがる (like having to use -て形, etc)？

Again, thanks for answering!